# Grails - Why doesn't an exception thrown in a controller halt the execution, but an exception thrown in a service does

Tags: grails, exception

1. Am I wrong to be throwing and exception within a controller?
2. Why doesn't an exception thrown in a controller halt the execution, but an exception thrown in a service does?
3. If it's possible, what am I missing to halt the execution and only execute the `handleCustomException` method when thrown from within a controller?

I have re-created this issue within a simple project to see if it was something crazy I had accidently done, but it seems its a default grails behaviour.

I have a single controller containing:

```
package simpletestproject

import simpleTestProject.exceptions.CustomException

class ExceptionTestController {

    SimpleService simpleService

    def index() {
        println("index called")
        someMethod()
        println("someMethod has been called")
    }

    def viaService() {
        println("viaService called")
        simpleService.serviceMethod()
        println("simpleService.someMethod has been called")
    }

    def someMethod() throws CustomException{
        println("foo... someMethod")
        throw new CustomException("some Response with an errocode", "You have seen an exception from the CONTROLLER")
        println("this should not be seen")
    }

    def handleCustomException(final CustomException exception){
        println("EXCEPTION CAUGHT - ${ exception.getErroneousResponse() } - ${ exception.getMessage() }")
        render("Exception Handled")
    }
}
```

and a single service containing:

```
package simpletestproject

import grails.transaction.Transactional
import simpleTestProject.exceptions.CustomException

@Transactional
class SimpleService {

    def serviceMethod() {
        println("serviceMethod")
        throw new CustomException("some Response with an errocode", "You have seen an exception from the SERVICE")
        println("serviceMethod - this should not be seen")
    }
}
```

If I navigate to http://localhost:8080/simpleTestProject/ExceptionTest I see the following printed:

```
index called
foo... someMethod
EXCEPTION CAUGHT - some Response with an errocode - You have seen an exception from the CONTROLLER
someMethod has been called
```

If I navigate to http://localhost:8080/simpleTestProject/ExceptionTest/viaService I see the following printed:

```
viaService called
serviceMethod
EXCEPTION CAUGHT - some Response with an errocode - You have seen an exception from the SERVICE
```

FYI - my CustomException is as follows:

```
package simpleTestProject.exceptions

class CustomException extends RuntimeException {

    private Object erroneousResponse

    public CustomException(Object erroneousResponse, String message) {
        super(message)
        if(erroneousResponse == null) {
            this.erroneousResponse = "NULL Response"
        }
        else {
            this.erroneousResponse = erroneousResponse
        }
    }

    public Object getErroneousResponse() {
        return this.erroneousResponse
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

**EDIT:**

I've also tried calling `someMethod` directly (http://localhost:8080/simpleTestProject/ExceptionTest/someMethod) and am seeing the below output:

```
foo... someMethod
EXCEPTION CAUGHT - some Response with an errocode - You have seen an exception from the CONTROLLER
```

This aligns with the behaviour of the service, and what I expect to see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not just call one action from another in a Grails controller.  (someMethod() is an action, because it is a non-private method in a controller.)

You could redirect to it, or include it, if you want.  Or you could make it a private method (then it's not an action any more and you can keep calling it the way you are now), or move it to a service.  But it's in general not going to go the way you want to just call one action explicitly from another like this.

The basic explanation is that actions have special handling added to them by the default grails controller.  Depending on which version of grails you're using, it does vary a bit, but basically they're going to handle their params and any exceptions in some common way.

Comment: Maybe a link to of this special handling would be good? It's not something that I have seen in docs. Accepting as making it a private method worked for me. Thanks